# How to add a layout in another one?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I need to hold my every view in one layout, so that i can move them all at once... But when i tried to put them all in a layout which should be in another main layout, they cannot be seen. What am i doing wrong?

I found out that the layout called leftLayout cannot be seen. I made different colours of layouts and it showed me the main one, called menu. I tried visibility true but it didn't work as well.

My design page is like this:

[image]

It should appear like this, but i see only white window when i compile...

Here's my Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/menu"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Left Menu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***Solved!*** I figured out that i was just doing mistake in java codes, while setting margin. So here the code's allright.

Comment: your question is not so clear. change child Relativelayou to Linear. and hard code your list view height once and check it.

Comment: didn't work. I found out that the layout called leftLayout cannot be seen. I made different colours of layouts and it showed me the main one, called menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relative layout you always need specify the location of each child with respect to the parent or the between the children. Since you have specified the layout all the layouts will be copied one over the other. You can use child alignment options like "ABOVE", "BELOW" w.r.t to other layouts.
The below code looked like what you wanted,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/menu" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/leftLayout" 
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true" 
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignleft="@+id/menu" > 

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/leftMenu" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:text="Left Menu" 
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:textColor="#000000" /> 

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:enabled="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/leftMenu" > 
</ListView> 

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tried to put "android:layout_above="@+id/menu" in layout leftMenu, but it didn't work :/

Comment: I see that "menu" is your parent Ralative layout, which covers the width and height of the screen. How can you add something above this!

Comment: Thanks, but I figured out that i was just doing mistake in java codes, while setting margin. So here the code's allright.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative layout yet you have not specified the location of the child views relative to each other.

In Relative layout you must specify this, look here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with LinearLayouts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="Left Menu"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```